# Nexus 5X loses GSM connection permanently while roaming

Tags: nexus-5, sim-card, gsm

Sometimes (perhaps once or twice per week), while driving car, using mobile network ("blitzer.de" app) and roaming between different network cells (only cells but same provider), my Nexus 5X (Android 7.1.2) loses GSM network connection permanently.   The network icon shows "emergency calls only" in this case.

I tried:

- entering/leaving flight mode
- scanning for networks

  - selecting my provider --> "SIM card does not support this network"
  - automatic registration --> either "registered" (but still "emergency calls only") or "SIM card does not support this network"
- switching data mode to 2G, 3G and 4G

None of these actions helped; only a reboot of the device.

Problem appeared 1 month ago or so; phone worked flawless for one year before. My provider is german "1&1".

Does this indicate a problem with the hardware of the phone, android, the SIM card or with my provider?

### UPDATE

When scanning networks I get:

#### Error case

```
05-15 11:55:29.276  6723  6723 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo Vodafone.de/Vodafone/26202/UNKNOWN
05-15 11:55:29.277  6723  6723 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo 1&1/1&1/26203/AVAILABLE
05-15 11:55:29.277  6723  6723 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo 1&1/1&1/26207/AVAILABLE
05-15 11:55:29.277  6723  6723 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo Telekom.de/TDG/26201/AVAILABLE
```

#### Success case (after reboot)

```
05-15 13:30:01.757  6844  6844 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo 1&1/1&1/26203/AVAILABLE
05-15 13:30:01.757  6844  6844 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo Vodafone.de/Vodafone/26202/FORBIDDEN
05-15 13:30:01.758  6844  6844 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo Telekom.de/TDG/26201/FORBIDDEN
05-15 13:30:01.758  6844  6844 D phone   : [NetworksList]   OperatorInfo 1&1/1&1/26207/CURRENT
```

#### Log while losing network

```
05-15 11:00:54.906  4829  4873 I VrManagerService: VR mode is disallowed
05-15 11:00:55.100  4829  4921 I PowerManagerService: Dozing...
05-15 11:00:55.101  4829  4916 I DreamController: Starting dream: name=ComponentInfo{com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.doze.DozeService}, isTest=false, canDoze=true, userId=0
05-15 11:00:55.147  4829 23863 I ActivityManager: Setting hasTopUi=true for pid=6520
05-15 11:03:47.670  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration mccmnc='null' fromServiceState=true
05-15 11:03:47.671  6723  6723 D MccTable: WIFI_COUNTRY_CODE set to 
05-15 11:03:47.728  4829  4829 I Telecom : CallLogManager: Country ISO changed. Retrieving new ISO...: CLM.<CLM>@Am4
05-15 11:03:47.735  4829 23866 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))(lbl:  -> 1&1)(desc:  -> 1&1)]: TSI.<TSI>@Am8
05-15 11:03:47.738  4829 23866 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@Am8
05-15 11:03:47.768  4829 23606 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))]: TSI.<TSI>@AnI
05-15 11:03:47.771  4829 23606 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@AnI
05-15 11:04:36.616  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration mccmnc='26203' fromServiceState=true
05-15 11:04:36.617  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration defaultMccMnc=26203
05-15 11:04:36.617  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=262, mnc=3
05-15 11:04:36.617  6723  6723 D MccTable: WIFI_COUNTRY_CODE set to de
05-15 11:04:36.673  4829  4829 I Telecom : CallLogManager: Country ISO changed. Retrieving new ISO...: CLM.<CLM>@AnM
05-15 11:04:36.680  4829  6749 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))(lbl: 1&1 -> )(desc: 1&1 -> )]: TSI.<TSI>@AnQ
05-15 11:04:36.683  4829  6749 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@AnQ
05-15 11:04:36.716  4829 23593 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))]: TSI.<TSI>@Anc
05-15 11:04:36.719  4829 23593 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@Anc
05-15 11:04:36.752  4829 23606 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))]: TSI.<TSI>@Ano
05-15 11:04:36.755  4829 23606 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@Ano
05-15 11:05:05.767  4829  8884 I PowerManagerService: Waking up from dozing (uid 10029)...
05-15 11:05:05.821  4829  4918 E WindowManager: Timeout waiting for animation to startup
05-15 11:05:05.822  4829  4916 I DreamController: Stopping dream: name=ComponentInfo{com.android.systemui/com.android.systemui.doze.DozeService}, isTest=false, canDoze=true, userId=0
05-15 11:05:06.226  4829  8888 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@f61930f attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@3f45f9c, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b7d73a8
05-15 11:05:06.245  4829  4921 I VrManagerService: VR mode is allowed
05-15 11:05:09.982  4829  4872 D ConnectivityService: requestNetwork for uid/pid:1000/4829 NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=194, legacyType=3, [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
05-15 11:05:11.078  4829 23599 D ConnectivityService: registerNetworkAgent NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: MOBILE[EDGE], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: internet.eplus.de, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]}  network{167}  nethandle{717275974366}  lp{{InterfaceName: rmnet_data0 LinkAddresses: [10.34.123.193/30,]  Routes: [0.0.0.0/0 -> 10.34.123.194 rmnet_data0,] DnsAddresses: [62.109.121.17,62.109.121.18,] Domains: null MTU: 1500 TcpBufferSizes: 4093,26280,35040,4096,16384,35040}}  nc{[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=59Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=236Kbps Specifier: <1>]}  Score{10}  everValidated{false}  lastValidated{false}  created{false} lingering{false} explicitlySelected{false} acceptUnvalidated{false} everCaptivePortalDetected{false} lastCaptivePortalDetected{false} }
05-15 11:05:11.078  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 167] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from null to CONNECTED
05-15 11:05:11.084  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Adding iface rmnet_data0 to network 167
05-15 11:05:11.123  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Setting DNS servers for network 167 to [/62.109.121.17, /62.109.121.18]
05-15 11:05:11.152  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending CONNECTED broadcast for type 3 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 167] isDefaultNetwork=false
05-15 11:05:11.172  4829  4872 D ConnectivityService: Adding legacy route 115.0.0.0/32 -> 10.34.123.194 rmnet_data0 for UID/PID 1000/4829
05-15 11:05:11.173  4829  4872 D ConnectivityService: requestRouteToHostAddress ok=true
05-15 11:05:12.035  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=194, legacyType=3, [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
05-15 11:05:12.036  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: no live requests for NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 167]; disconnecting
05-15 11:05:12.036  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending DISCONNECTED broadcast for type 3 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 167] isDefaultNetwork=false
05-15 11:05:12.037  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 167] got DISCONNECTED, was satisfying 6
05-15 11:05:16.539  4829  4829 W WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@24c5f90
05-15 11:05:22.599  4829  4829 W WindowManager: Attempted to remove non-existing token: android.os.Binder@cb577e0
05-15 11:06:10.618  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 166] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from CONNECTED to DISCONNECTED
05-15 11:06:10.618  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 166] got DISCONNECTED, was satisfying 10
05-15 11:06:10.654  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending DISCONNECTED broadcast for type 1 NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 166] isDefaultNetwork=true
05-15 11:06:11.782  4829 23424 D ConnectivityService: registerNetworkAgent NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: MOBILE[EDGE], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: internet.eplus.de, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]}  network{168}  nethandle{721570941662}  lp{{InterfaceName: rmnet_data0 LinkAddresses: [10.41.216.1/30,]  Routes: [0.0.0.0/0 -> 10.41.216.2 rmnet_data0,] DnsAddresses: [62.109.121.17,62.109.121.18,] Domains: null MTU: 1500 TcpBufferSizes: 4093,26280,35040,4096,16384,35040}}  nc{[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=59Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=236Kbps Specifier: <1>]}  Score{10}  everValidated{false}  lastValidated{false}  created{false} lingering{false} explicitlySelected{false} acceptUnvalidated{false} everCaptivePortalDetected{false} lastCaptivePortalDetected{false} }
05-15 11:06:11.782  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from null to CONNECTED
05-15 11:06:11.785  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Adding iface rmnet_data0 to network 168
05-15 11:06:11.828  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Setting DNS servers for network 168 to [/62.109.121.17, /62.109.121.18]
05-15 11:06:11.868  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Switching to new default network: NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: MOBILE[EDGE], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: internet.eplus.de, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]}  network{168}  nethandle{721570941662}  lp{{InterfaceName: rmnet_data0 LinkAddresses: [10.41.216.1/30,]  Routes: [0.0.0.0/0 -> 10.41.216.2 rmnet_data0,] DnsAddresses: [62.109.121.17,62.109.121.18,] Domains: null MTU: 1500 TcpBufferSizes: 4093,26280,35040,4096,16384,35040}}  nc{[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND LinkUpBandwidth>=59Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=236Kbps Specifier: <1>]}  Score{10}  everValidated{false}  lastValidated{false}  created{true} lingering{false} explicitlySelected{false} acceptUnvalidated{false} everCaptivePortalDetected{false} lastCaptivePortalDetected{false} }
05-15 11:06:11.880  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending CONNECTED broadcast for type 0 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] isDefaultNetwork=true
05-15 11:06:14.373  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] validation passed
05-15 11:06:15.025  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration mccmnc='26207' fromServiceState=true
05-15 11:06:15.026  4829  4829 D ConditionProviders.SCP: onReceive android.intent.action.TIME_SET
05-15 11:06:15.028  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration defaultMccMnc=26203
05-15 11:06:15.028  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=262, mnc=7
05-15 11:06:15.028  6723  6723 D MccTable: WIFI_COUNTRY_CODE set to de
05-15 11:06:15.107  4829 23865 D ConnectivityService: reportNetworkConnectivity(168, false) by 10013
05-15 11:06:15.126  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] validation failed
05-15 11:06:15.128  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: handleNetworkUnvalidated NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] cap=[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND LinkUpBandwidth>=59Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=236Kbps Specifier: <1>]
05-15 11:06:15.208  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from CONNECTED to DISCONNECTED
05-15 11:06:15.209  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] got DISCONNECTED, was satisfying 9
05-15 11:06:15.232  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending DISCONNECTED broadcast for type 0 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 168] isDefaultNetwork=true
05-15 11:06:16.368  4829  6749 I ActivityManager: Start proc 7815:com.qualcomm.timeservice/1000 for broadcast com.qualcomm.timeservice/.TimeServiceBroadcastReceiver
05-15 11:06:16.400  4829 23424 D ConnectivityService: registerNetworkAgent NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: MOBILE[LTE], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: internet.eplus.de, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]}  network{169}  nethandle{725865908958}  lp{{InterfaceName: rmnet_data0 LinkAddresses: [10.34.9.20/29,]  Routes: [0.0.0.0/0 -> 10.34.9.21 rmnet_data0,] DnsAddresses: [62.109.121.17,62.109.121.18,] Domains: null MTU: 1500 TcpBufferSizes: 2097152,4194304,8388608,262144,524288,1048576}}  nc{[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN LinkUpBandwidth>=51200Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=102400Kbps Specifier: <1>]}  Score{10}  everValidated{false}  lastValidated{false}  created{false} lingering{false} explicitlySelected{false} acceptUnvalidated{false} everCaptivePortalDetected{false} lastCaptivePortalDetected{false} }
05-15 11:06:16.401  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (LTE) - 169] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from null to CONNECTED
05-15 11:06:16.402  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Adding iface rmnet_data0 to network 169
05-15 11:06:16.441  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Setting DNS servers for network 169 to [/62.109.121.17, /62.109.121.18]
05-15 11:06:16.463  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Switching to new default network: NetworkAgentInfo{ ni{[type: MOBILE[LTE], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: connected, extra: internet.eplus.de, failover: false, available: true, roaming: false, metered: true]}  network{169}  nethandle{725865908958}  lp{{InterfaceName: rmnet_data0 LinkAddresses: [10.34.9.20/29,]  Routes: [0.0.0.0/0 -> 10.34.9.21 rmnet_data0,] DnsAddresses: [62.109.121.17,62.109.121.18,] Domains: null MTU: 1500 TcpBufferSizes: 2097152,4194304,8388608,262144,524288,1048576}}  nc{[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND LinkUpBandwidth>=51200Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=102400Kbps Specifier: <1>]}  Score{10}  everValidated{false}  lastValidated{false}  created{true} lingering{false} explicitlySelected{false} acceptUnvalidated{false} everCaptivePortalDetected{false} lastCaptivePortalDetected{false} }
05-15 11:06:16.468  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending CONNECTED broadcast for type 0 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (LTE) - 169] isDefaultNetwork=true
05-15 11:06:16.894  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (LTE) - 169] validation passed
05-15 11:10:09.933  4829  4872 D ConnectivityService: requestNetwork for uid/pid:1000/4829 NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=199, legacyType=3, [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
05-15 11:10:09.936  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending CONNECTED broadcast for type 3 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 169] isDefaultNetwork=true
05-15 11:10:09.956  4829  4872 D ConnectivityService: Adding legacy route 115.0.0.0/32 -> 10.34.9.21 rmnet_data0 for UID/PID 1000/4829
05-15 11:10:09.960  4829  4872 D ConnectivityService: requestRouteToHostAddress ok=true
05-15 11:10:10.756  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: releasing NetworkRequest [ REQUEST id=199, legacyType=3, [ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN] ]
05-15 11:10:10.757  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending DISCONNECTED broadcast for type 3 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (EDGE) - 169] isDefaultNetwork=false
05-15 11:14:28.041  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration mccmnc='26203' fromServiceState=true
05-15 11:14:28.042  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration defaultMccMnc=26203
05-15 11:14:28.042  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration: mcc=262, mnc=3
05-15 11:14:28.042  6723  6723 D MccTable: WIFI_COUNTRY_CODE set to de
05-15 11:14:32.177  6723  6723 D MccTable: updateMccMncConfiguration mccmnc='null' fromServiceState=true
05-15 11:14:32.177  6723  6723 D MccTable: WIFI_COUNTRY_CODE set to 
05-15 11:14:32.245  4829  4829 I Telecom : CallLogManager: Country ISO changed. Retrieving new ISO...: CLM.<CLM>@An8
05-15 11:14:32.264  4829  7006 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))(lbl:  -> 1&1)(desc:  -> 1&1)]: TSI.<TSI>@AoA
05-15 11:14:32.267  4829  7006 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@AoA
05-15 11:14:32.324  4829  7185 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))]: TSI.<TSI>@AoM
05-15 11:14:32.327  4829  7185 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@AoM
05-15 11:14:34.576  4829  7171 D ConnectivityService: reportNetworkConnectivity(169, false) by 10013
05-15 11:14:34.610  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 169] validation failed
05-15 11:14:34.613  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: handleNetworkUnvalidated NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 169] cap=[ Transports: CELLULAR Capabilities: SUPL&INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&NOT_VPN&FOREGROUND LinkUpBandwidth>=5898Kbps LinkDnBandwidth>=14336Kbps Specifier: <1>]
05-15 11:14:34.690  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 169] EVENT_NETWORK_INFO_CHANGED, going from CONNECTED to DISCONNECTED
05-15 11:14:34.690  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 169] got DISCONNECTED, was satisfying 11
05-15 11:14:34.714  4829  6358 D ConnectivityService: Sending DISCONNECTED broadcast for type 0 NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (HSPA) - 169] isDefaultNetwork=true
05-15 11:14:34.856  4829  7185 I ActivityManager: Killing 6109:com.lge.lifetimer/u0a21 (adj 906): empty #17
05-15 11:14:34.927  4829 23595 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 6109
05-15 11:14:36.210  4829 23863 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))]: TSI.<TSI>@AoQ
05-15 11:14:36.214  4829 23863 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@AoQ
05-15 11:14:36.250  4829  7458 I Telecom : PhoneAccountRegistrar: [ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.services.telephony.TelephonyConnectionService}, [<redacted>], UserHandle{0}(icon: Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63) -> Icon(typ=BITMAP size=50x63))]: TSI.<TSI>@Aoc
05-15 11:14:36.255  4829  7458 I Telecom : : Sending phone-account registered intent as user: TSI.<TSI>@Aoc
05-15 11:14:37.975  4829  9126 W LocationBasedCountryDetector: Exception occurs when getting country from location
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Access Point Names (APN)?
Try to insert them manually (you may find them on your mobile operator's site).
If this solution doesn't work check the SIM slot.
Just a little question: did the problem arise after a system update?

Comment: Are APN settings really interesting for voice calls?  Because problem happens only once or twice per week, it is is difficultly to say whether it started after an Android update.